# How to make cross domain XHR request

Tags: javascript, xss, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

How to make working XHR cross domain request - I've tried 'Script Tag Hack' but it doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

I would like to call script in domain A from B.

**domain A:** [index.html]

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://evilDomain/xhrTest.js"></script>
</head>
```

**domain B:** [xhrTest.js]

```
$.ajax({
      url: "https://evilDomain/processRequest",
      success: function(result){
        alert(result);
      }
});
```

**edited**:

I've also tried to use JSONP in this way:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "https://evilDomain/processRequest",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(result){
        alert(result);
      }
});
```

I'm using TOMCAT container, is the solution connected with **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would ask your server to do the request for you.

The other option is to let someone else do that for you (such as Yahoo's service).

Your problem is that **domain B**'s code is still executed in the context of **domain A**.
Hence, `https://evilDomain/processRequest` still cannot be read because the code is executing as **domain A** even if in truth it came from **domain B**.

Comment: Yeah, the clearest (without hacks) solution is using server which does request for me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header to your server responses.  This will allow you to make cross-domain requests.

You can then further customise as required with **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** and **Access-Control-Allow-Headers**.

For more details see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control

Comment: yeah, but it isn't good solution for me - it should be compatible with most browsers (even ie6)

Comment: Then JSONP is your only option.

Comment: but I also need to do login form, so I must not pass credentials in URL

Answer (score 1):

use JSONP or have a service on your own domain call the other domain on the server-side and get what you need that way.

Comment: I thought about it, but I'm creating login form. When I would used JSONP I have to pass all parameters in the URL

Comment: Why pass them in the url? Do a POST, not a GET.

Comment: as wikipedia says (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) you need to import script using script tag, so it is GET. Can you propose your version with POST?

Comment: @smas - My bad. Damn you wikipedia! ;)

Comment: @smas - I think in this case, you need to do a POST to your own server and do all the authentication and getting of data through your own service that calls the other domain's service as it's not wise to do a login via GET with the login info in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The domain B JS is being included in the page, then being executed from the page which originates from domain A, hence the problem. To do this cross domain you need to request the data response as a "script" itself, then parse it from there.